# MariaDB formatting view code

Tags: mysql, linux, view, formatting, mariadb

When i save view on mariadb on debian(6) I lose comments and formatting of code. What is this feature of mariadb? How turn if off? On windows instance all comments and formats are stored.

Both instances is MariaDB 10.0.17.
Managed with Heidi 9.1 from Windows.

Edit 1.
Semi solved. LOAD_FILE for view.frm return null, cause of file permission. Chmod od this file is 660 file own mysql, group mysql. When i manualy put i.e. 666 chmod all works. Deamon is run by mysql user. Managed with mariadb root user, which has grant file privilege.

Edit 2.
LOAD_FILE work only for files which has read flag for all users, owner of the file does not matter... Also I have been tested on ubuntu 14.04 lts and same problem occur. Seems like mariadb debian/ubuntu bug...
I used auditd to check access to file. When file does not have read flag for all no event has occurred...
Any ideas?

Edit 3.
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/load_file/
File must be read for all...

So the question is: **how set default chmod(read for all flag) for .frm (or all...) files?** (temporarily, for develop time)

Comment: Explain the steps that lead to the loss.

Comment: Semi solved. LOAD_FILE for view.frm return null, cause of file permission. Chmod od this file is 660 file own mysql, group mysql. When i manualy put i.e. 666 chmod all works. Deamon is run by mysql user. Managed with mariadb root user, which has grant file privilege.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved. HeidiSQL try to load view query from .frm file by `LOAD_FILE` function, which need file with read for all flag. Default creation mode db files are 0660 (and 0700 for directories). We can change it by include to start script (i.e. /etc/init.d/mysql) i.e. `export UMASK=064` (which is OR - not AND) more on: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/specifying-permissions-for-schema-data-directories-and-tables/

Answer (score 1):

This helped me a lot! Thanks!

[https://mariadb.com/kb/en/systemd/#configuring-the-umask]

```
sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/umask.conf <<EOF
[Service]

Environment="UMASK=0664"
EOF
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

And views are saved and read again by HeidiSQL unchanged (with comments/linebreaks/etc.).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have another answer for my environment (Mariadb 10.1 + Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Create a new file;
/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/MY_SPECIAL.conf containing the following lines;

[Service]

Environment="UMASK=0664"

This seems to set the permissions for frm to -rw-rw-r-- while allows LOAD_FILE to read the view / stored proc / other source.

I hope this helps someone else!